# Как применить implode к двумерному массиву

Tags: php, ооп, mysqli

Дано - двумерный массив

```
$ins = array(
        'type_product' => (
          array (
            'post' => $_POST['type_product'],
            'name' => 'Тип продукта',
          )
        ),
        'company_product' => (
          array (
            'post' => $_POST['company_product'],
            'name' => 'Компания',
          )
        ),
        'color_product' => (
          array (
            'post' => $_POST['color_product'],
            'name' => 'Цвет продукта',
          )
        ),
        'line_product' => (
          array (
            'post' => $_POST['line_product'],
            'name' => 'Линейка',
          )
        ),
        'bend_product' => (
          array (
            'post' => $_POST['bend_product'],
            'name' => 'Изгиб',
          )
        ),
        'thickness_product' => (
          array (
            'post' => $_POST['thickness_product'],
            'name' => 'Толщина',
          )
        ),
        'long_product' => (
          array (
            'post' => $_POST['long_product'],
            'name' => 'Длина',
          )
        ),
        'unit_of_measure_product' => (
          array (
            'post' => $_POST['unit_of_measure_product'],
            'name' => 'Еденица измерения',
          )
        ),
        'price_product' => (
          array (
            'post' => $_POST['price_product'],
            'name' => 'Цена',
          )
        ),
        'mix_product' => (
          array (
            'post' => $_POST['mix_product'],
            'name' => 'Набор',
          )
        ),
        'quantity_product' => (
          array (
            'post' => $_POST['quantity_product'],
            'name' => 'Количество',
          )
        ),
        'lines_product' => (
          array (
            'post' => $_POST['lines_product'],
            'name' => 'Линии',
          )
        ),
        'size_product' => (
          array (
            'post' => $_POST['size_product'],
            'name' => 'Размер',
          )
        ),
        'composition_product' => (
          array (
            'post' => $_POST['composition_product'],
            'name' => 'Состав',
          )
        ),
        'description_product' => (
          array (
            'post' => $_POST['description_product'],
            'name' => 'Описание',
          )
        ),
        'image_product' => $uploadfile,
);
```

Есть функция:

```
public function insert($table, $params = array())
{
    if ($this->tableExist($table))
    {
        $stringQuery = 'INSERT INTO `' . $table . '` (`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($params)) . '`) VALUES ("' . implode('", "', $params) . '")';
        $this->sqlQuery($stringQuery);
    }

}
```

Каким образом мне извлечь содержимое ключей post? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: смущает 'image_product' => $uploadfile,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

не совсем понял зачем вам `implode`, думаю достаточно `$first_names = array_column($ins, 'post');`

```html
$first_names = array_column($ins, 'post');//создаем массив по ключу
$res = implode(",", $first_names);// добавляем запятую

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);//выводим результат
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Вы гений. Спасибо большое. Надежно, минималистично и лаконично.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function insert($table, $params = array())
{
    if ($this->tableExist($table))
    {
        foreach($params as $param){
            if(is_array($param) && !empty($param)){
                $values[] = $param['post'];
            }
        }
        $stringQuery = 'INSERT INTO `' . $table . '` (`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($params)) . '`) VALUES ("' . implode('", "', $values) . '")';
        $this->sqlQuery($stringQuery);
    }
}
```